# [Linx Mint - Mate 1.8} Is there a zoom/scale applet?

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop

Is there an Applet I can add to my Mint Panel which I can change the screen scale with?  I don't want to be able to zoom just wherever the cursor is, but instead to have everything enlarge by a small amount during the night when I have difficulty reading the screen due to my farsightedness.

I know that Gnome-Shell has two extensions which can do this:

1. ["Text Scaler"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1018/text-scaler/)
2. ["Toggle Zoom"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1012/toggle-zoom/)

If there is not an applet that do this, I would also be happy to know any command that could do and undo this for me.  Then I'll just make custom applets using the Panel's Custom Application applet.

Right now I can't even find an option to do this in my Control Center, but there's always a chance that I just can't find it for some unexplainable reason.  Like when you forget why you went to the fridge.

Many thanks!

~ Ev

Comment: How about `xrandr` such as (to change my eDP1 display, the laptop screen) `xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 0.8x0.8`. (just `xrandr` on its own, will give a list of display + other info on the displays.)

Comment: Thanks for the input . Is there an xrandr GUI version?

Comment: Yes many, but the ones I have seen do a limited subset. You could do your own. For example KDE has a customizable widget, that allows one to associate a script and an icon.